# Making an image full width, for all browsers (bg)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my banner image which is currently around 1500px wide full width, I have set it as a background image so I can play with a few elements ontop, I understand you can make an image tag full width, but i'm not sure if you can do the same with a background image tag!

this is my code;

```
<div id="bannerbg">
     <div class="container">
          <p id="bannertxt">demo text</p>
     </div>
</div>

.container{
    width:980px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

#bannerbg{
    background-image:url('../images/banner.png');
    width:1520px;
    height:369px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin:0px auto;
    position: absolute;
}

#bannertxt{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    font-size:26px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    width:300px;
    color:white;
}

.bannertxt{
    padding-top:40px;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705367/creating-a-full-width-image/16706285#16706285 please see the answer here

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/YmSB6/) is a working example.

Comment: OO, I gimmie a second to test I dont want it full height so lemme change that value a second, this didn't work for me ;/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
#bannerbg{
  /*Your code*/
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: thats a full screen one I need a fixed height just full width :)

Comment: @TidalWave - Yes I noticed as well :) But the only different solution for IE is to create another element with img tag..