# Creating a full width image

Tags: html, css, image, web

I would just like the edges of my image to stretch the width of the screen. Not looking for it to be a full background.

My website is www.jobspark.ca

```
<div class="fullWidthSectionBG">
<div class="fullWidthSection">
<div class="myLeftColumn">        
<p>
</p> 
</div>
<div class="myRightColumn">
<h2>Used By Thousands Of Canadians</h2>
<p>Jobspark.ca is dedicated to providing resources for job seekers and employers throughout British Columbia and Alberta. Many top employers along with small local businesses from across the region post their jobs on Job Spark to find qualified professionals.</p>
<p>Job Spark simplifies your quest for the perfect career with a clean design and real-time postings. Our streamline job board was designed to take the headache out of finding a job.</p>
<p>Your job listings will be seen across multiple venues, receiving thousands of views each month! </p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

the CSS

```
.fullWidthSectionBG { 
background-image: url('http://static.squarespace.com/static/513d5347e4b0abff73be5264/t/519c45c4e4b084baf13d7e27/1369195972115/rocktruck2.jpg');
background-position:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;  
height:575px;
margin-left: -1600px; 
margin-right: -1600px;  
}
```

[image: Might have to zoom out to see see issue.]

This answer was close but then the rest of the website that isn't an image extended full screen.

```
#site > .wrapper {
max-width: 960px;
padding: 0 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

change 960px to 100%

& get rid of

```
margin-left: -1600px;
margin-right: -1600px;
```

I have been fighting with this issue for a few days now and would be soo happy to figure something out. Might have to zoom out to see the issue.

Comment: It goes full width for me in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: Seems to work in FireFox 1280x1024

Comment: I am using chrome as well. But not full screen for me... Not sure why. I am viewing with site with wide monitor

Answer (score 0):

What about adding

```
width: 100%;
```

to your css rules and getting rid of the margins ? like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mBDx5/1/)

Is that your question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#site > .wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

change 960px to 100%

& get rid of

```
margin-left: -1600px;
margin-right: -1600px;
```

Comment: This works but then messes with the width for the rest of my site. Would like it to just focus on the the image section

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this goal i typically define a div element that fits the exact size and position i want my background image to fill.

then use the css attribute for background-size:cover;  this Cover attribute scales the image automatically to ensure the entire background area is in fact "covered" by image.  [see the documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

[here is a jsfiddle of an example of this method working](http://jsfiddle.net/UKBXv/4/)

it is also worth noting to achieve intermittent full width areas between centered fixed width areas i like to use this method of defining a .wrapper class very similar to yours.  then ending that wrapper for the full width area and once again restarting it afterwards

my adjustments to your code as follows:

CSS

```
.fullWidthSectionBG { 
    background-image: url('http://static.squarespace.com/static/513d5347e4b0abff73be5264/t/519c45c4e4b084baf13d7e27/1369195972115/rocktruck2.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    height:575px;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <!-- HEADER HERE -->
</div>

<div class="fullWidthSectionBG">
     <div class="wrapper">
          <!-- FULL WIDTH BANNER CONTENT HERE -->
     </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
     <!-- BODY HERE -->
</div>
```

try it out let me know how it works - hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. The two edges of the image did no expand to the edges of the screen.

Comment: i tried to imply this but guess i didnt say it outright but your .fullWidthSectionBG needs to outside of any elements constraining its width.  background-size:cover; will only achieve your desired effect if that div has a true 100% width of the document.  using margins is just going to "fake" it but there will always be a breaking point